# How do I open a url with post values into a browser in python?

Tags: python, highcharts, jsfiddle

I am trying to create highcharts and post the code into jsfiddle, I can get the responses, but I can not figure out how to actually open it into a browser.

```
query_args = {// post varibales}
encoded_args = urllib.parse.urlencode(query_args)
url = 'http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/mootools/1.2/dependencies/more/'
request = urllib.request.Request(url,encoded_args.encode())
print(urllib.request.urlopen(request).read())
```

This returns the request and prints it, but i want to actually open it all in a browser so I can see it

Comment: try [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you..!

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://your_url.com')
```

Comment: I have looked at this, but I can't find a way to go:
    webbrowser.open('http://your_url.com', 'post variables')
Or some other equivilent